# Calculating the area of a paraboloid inside a cylinder

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, area

So I have to calculate the area of a paraboloid $2z=\frac{x^2}{a}+\frac{y^2}{b}$ inside a cylinder $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$. So I plugged in my formula:
$$\iint_R\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)^2}dA$$
The terms in square root simplify to $\sqrt2$ if I have did math correctly,
But I am having difficulty in limits and subsequent solving. I thought of letting $x$ vary from $-a\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2}$ to $a\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{y}{b}\right)^2}$ and later $y$ as $-b$ to $b$.

I thought of using polar coordinates but I dont know how to apply it in case of ellipse where $r$ is variable so i would like an answer solving and explain by polar coordinates. Nevertheless, I am getting the wrong answer, so I really would appreciate some other method besides this formula. Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: For starters, the integrand is certainly not $\sqrt 2$. For example, what is it at the origin? If you know about change of variables in double integrals, suitably stretched polar coordinates would be ideal.

Comment: **Hint**: Let $u=\frac{x}{a}$ and $v=\frac{y}{b}$. This leads to $ab\iint_R\sqrt{1+u^2+v^2}\mathrm du \mathrm dv$. Now you can proceed with polar coordinates.